# NVDA says table columns name an extra time when a link is present

Tags: html-table, accessibility

I understand that depending on the screen reader and browser one is using, NVDA and Chrome, for example, table columns are read out more than once.  However, when including a link in the header, NVDA will say column name an additional time. This seems a bit redundant.

A solution I came up with is merely putting the links in the next row.   When a person is navigating the site using the down arrow key and navigating line by line, this would not be a good solution.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best approach for this scenario?

Comment: Please could you provide a fiddle. I would imagine the advice will be the same as I often give in these scenarios which is "your HTML is valid and correct, stop trying to make a screen reader announce things the way you want as you will likely make accessibility worse" but without seeing the HTML it is impossible to tell and offer advice I am afraid.

Comment: Graham,

Thank you for your reply.   I figured why NVDA reading the table header more times than it should.    My table has four headings with a link.   Within the A tag, there is an aria-label with "{column heading} - details." Thus the reason  NVDA reads the heading more than necessary.

Aria-label is present to distinguish the links.  Since screen readers already say the column name, perhaps removing the column name from the aria-label is ideal.  Do you have any suggestions on how I should approach this?

Here is a link to the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rcorr/ouL2qbrf/22/

Comment: Sometimes, repetition helps.  Hearing things twice might annoy some, but help others.